# How to delegate each() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

It is possible to delegate .each() function in jquery? I want to bind my Div to li using delegate while using each(). Someone please help. Thanks in advance

I have this code

```
$('.calendar-container .item-list ul').each(function(){
    $(this).slick({
        slide: 'li',
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
    });
});
```

I want something like this but its not working

```
 $(document).delegate('.calendar-container .item-list ul','each',function(){
        alert('dd')
        $(this).slick({
            slide: 'li',
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3
        });
    });
```

Comment: What do expect from this code to do exactly?

Comment: Does delegate could apply to each() function

Comment: Delegate is deprecated as of jQuery 3 and I'm not sure what do you mean by this specific usage... Lets say you can do this - what do you expect from this code to do? You question is not clear.

Comment: `delegate` works on events. what do you want to delgate each to mean?

Comment: I want to bind my div to my li using delegate while using each @DanielA.White

Comment: there's no `each` event.

Comment: @Paul That explanation is still confusing.  What, specifically, do you want to do?

Comment: ahhhh Thanks  @DanielA.White , but last question Is it possible to bind them?

Comment: `bind` works with events too.

Comment: @DanielA.White can you give me sample. Much appreciated.

Comment: of what? your not being clear at what you want to do by bind/delegate to each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You can't do this.  Delegation in jQuery is for handling events that bubble up the parent chain.  It appears you want to call `.slick()` on any newly created element that matches a selector.  You can't do that with delegation since it doesn't fit the above definition of how it works and what it does.  You aren't looking to handle an existing event that bubbles up the parent chain.

If you're looking for totally arbitrary monitoring of newly created objects or objects assigned matching classes, you'd probably have to use some sort of [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), though I suspect if we understood your entire situation, there's probably an easier and less generic way of solving your particular problem (like hooking into your code that modifies the DOM).